# PowerShell: Checking if file is English by using word-list

Tags: powershell

Here's the scenario:
I have a series of files in different languages and I need to figure out which of them is English.
My idea is to create an array of words, then check the files one by one for occurrences of those words. Finally, I add the occurrences of each word together. If the total is high enough, I'll assume the file is English.

After a bit of creative Googling I started out with this:

```
[System.Array]$Words = ' the ',' this ',' in ',' you ',' of ',' are ','music'

[System.String]$Content = Get-Content -Path <FileName>

ForEach ($Word in $Words) {
  $Count = [RegEx]::Matches($Content,[RegEx]::Escape($Word)).Count
  Write-Output -InputObject "$Word : $Count"
}
```

This shows me that it's working at least:

```
 the  : 172
 this  : 14
 in  : 52
 you  : 95
 of  : 61
 are  : 18
music : 0
```

So where do I go next?

I considered using `[System.Int32]$Hits = 0` and `$Hits++` to add them all together. Just trying to figure out how.

Also, when I check the same file with Notepad++, I get different counts, strangely enough. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ultimately the hard decision you're going to have to make is specifying exactly what you mean by "if the total is high enough". Summing up the total English word count is trivial, the threshold is the hard part (and you might consider setting a threshold for the total *proportion* of common English words than an absolute limit. Also take into account files like `music music of`).

Comment: Btw. you could download the scrabble dictionary, sowpods or something similar, then close to 100% of the words should be detected and a boundary of about 80% should give good results. And you only have to iterate over the text once and check for each word if it is english.

Comment: I'd have to find words that have a high occurrence in English and a low occurrence in other languages (one of the reasons I put the leading and trailing spaces around the words in the array is to avoid words containing those characters) and in so doing create a large difference making it easier to set a threshold. Which words those are is a question for another forum. With a large dictionary, I'd run the risk of too much overlap (English has a French heritage for example). @maraca, could you elaborate a bit more? RegEx is still a tough topic for me.

Comment: @Mark ok then the difference is more subtle, but `" word "` is still not the same as `\bword\b`. Word boundaries can be returns `\n` or also punctuation, those are words you are missing by just putting spaces around the word. Also note that regex are usually case-sensitive unless specified otherwise.

Comment: @Mark there are actually not that many words in english and you could store them in a hash map (sorry I don't know powershell, so I don't know what exists there), checking if a word is in the map is O(1). And yes there are common words, but still French is very different from English, think about it, if 80% of the words would be the same you would have no problem undestanding other European languages. 2 errors in 10 words is high if it is actually that language, but not if it is not. Btw. German, French and English could probably be differentiated only by looking at the umlauts and accents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of outputting a string, output an object and store those in a variable!

```
$stringCounts = foreach ($Word in $Words) {
  $Count = [RegEx]::Matches($Content,[RegEx]::Escape($Word)).Count
  New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Word = $Word
    Count = $Count
  }
}
```

Now you can easily get the sum of individual counts with `Measure-Object`:

```
$TotalCount = ($stringCounts |Measure-Object Count -Sum).Sum
```

Comment: That should be:

    `($stringCounts | Measure-Object -Property Count -Sum).Sum`

Without the `-Property Count` I get an exception.

Using an object makes it more professional though, so thank you.

I could then possibly use the returned number to compare to the threshold.

I'll wait for a bit to see if there are more ways to Rome, so to speak.

Comment: I guess there is only one road to Rome, since nobody came up with something different. Your solution helps me parse the results and answers the question asked, so I'll mark it as such. Thank you. I'll go and figure out how to work with the words from here.